# Who or what is permitted membership of a Mail Enabled Security Group

Tags: microsoft-office-365, entra-id

I'm wanting to know a complete list of permitted objects that can be members of the Mail-Enabled Security Group. Is there some official documentation that lists these? Google hasn't been my friend today, and I don't have access to the portal.

Comment: Any object can be a member of a group. For security groups, the member would need to be a security principal (user or computer) to be granted access to a resource.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients-in-exchange-online/manage-mail-enabled-security-groups